# How to query data matching ID and Date from another list of IDs and Dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains data on patient. The table has `Patient ID`, `AdmissionDate`, among other things. The same patient may have multiple `AdmissionDate`. I am interested in only a select patients whose admission date falls is in a select date. For e.g.: The table below

```
patient_id | admission_date
-----------+---------------
F001         2018-07-13
F002         2017-04-02
F003         2018-07-13
F004         2018-04-05
F005         2015-06-13
F001         2017-04-02
F002         2018-07-13
F001         2018-04-22
```

In the table above, `F001` has 3 admissions: `2018-07-13, 2017-04-02, 2018-04-22` and `F002` has 2: `2017-04-02, 2018-07-13`.

Now, I have a spreadsheet of the IDs with their admission dates in the next column. I took the IDs and dates separately, and added it to the following query

```
WITH TableA AS
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(date, admission_date) as admit_date, *
    FROM 
        AdmissionTable
    WHERE 
        patient_id IN ('F001', 'F002', 'F003', 'F004', 'F005') 
)
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE admit_date IN ('2018-07-13', '2017-04-02', '2018-07-13','2018-04-05,'2015-06-13','2017-04-02','2018-07-13','2018-04-22')
```

This returns the result I'm looking for but also more than what I'm looking for. It gives me even the rows of the patient whose admission date is also in the date list I'm searching for, not the ones that is listed in the spreadsheet. The query essentially gives me multiple data for the same patients rather than only the row with the date I need.

How can I fix this? What's the best way to handle it?

The desired result should be something like below:

```
patient_id | admission_date
-----------+---------------
F001         2018-04-22
F002         2018-07-13
F003         2018-07-13
F004         2018-04-05
F005         2015-06-13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking you should construct the query like this:

```
with from_spreadsheet as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('F001', '2018-07-13'), ('F002', '2017-04-02'), . . .
           ) v(patient_id, admission_date)
     )
select a.*
from admissiontable a join
     from_spreadsheet fs
     on fs.patient_id = a.patient_id and
        convert(date, fs.admission_date) = a.admission_date;
```

Comment: Okay, I'll give this a try. Seems logical.  Thank you

Comment: It returns this error - `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'F001'.`, and I also had to remove `v.` after `select`

Comment: Ah!! Got it!! You forgot `VALUES` after `FROM(` in `from_spreadsheet`. It's returned the results. I'm verifying if the results are what I needed.